# Firebug shows event handler in HTML panel but not in JavaScript panel

Tags: javascript, firebug

I inspected an element inside an iframe within Firebug. I am able to select the element in the page and it is shown within the *HTML* panel. The element has a JavaScript call on select, which I am unable to see within the *Script* panel to add a breakpoint to it.

[image: Function call in *HTML* panel]

I tried to call the function using the command line, though that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please add the related HTML code to make it clearer how the function call looks like? Also, did you already try to search the function within the *Script* panel using the [search field](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Search_Field)?

Comment: http://imgur.com/jektyDC   In this image I am unable to find loadTemplate() function to put break-point on. I tried search field, not showing. The page uses many iframes.

Answer (score 0):

The [*Events* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel) is where you can set a breakpoint for the event handler. While the element is selected, switch to that panel, right-click the `onchange(event)` event handler and choose *Set Breakpoint*.

[image: Set breakpoint on event handler]

Note that Firebug won't work anymore once [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) is enabled (which [seems to be the case in Firefox 49](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Schedule)).

As far as I can see, unfortunately, neither the Firefox nor the Chrome DevTools allow to set a breakpoint on the event handler. They only allow you to jump to the place where the handler is called within the HTML code.